# How to create a randomized timer that shows an output within a given duration in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to make a timer that goes off at a random time within a given duration in ruby coding.
Example:
Lets say the duration is set to 4 minutes but the timer goes off after 8 seconds
Set it to an hour an it goes off after 35 minutes.

Also i was told that `Gosu.milliseconds` would help but I'm not sure how to implement that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This solution works on vanilla ruby)

(Using version 2.6.6p146 (2020-03-31 revision 67876) [x64-mingw32])

There are many different ways to do this, but one solution would be to take advantage of the Unix Epoch time format. All Time objects in Ruby can be represented in terms of seconds since midnight on Janurary 1 1970.

To get the current time in Ruby:

```
t = Time.now
```

Nothing special. But you can convert the Time object into an integer (using the "to_i" method), and Ruby automatically will give you the Time object represented as the number of seconds elapsed since midnight on Janurary 1 1970.

```
Time.now.to_i # This returned 1589725307 when I ran it. Obviously it will be different each time
```

Using the "rand" function, you can implement your timer:

```
# the current time as an integer
t = Time.now.to_i

# set to 10 for example purposes, but it can be any positive integer
max_seconds = 10

# a random number of seconds between 1 and the maximum. 3, 7, and 8 are all possible values of "duration" in this case
duration = rand(1..max_seconds)

# the desired result time, when the timer will go off
end_time = t + duration

# run an infinite loop, which will terminate when the randomly generated 
# duration is over

while true
  if Time.now.to_i <= end_time
  else
    puts "Timer is done"
    break
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[sleep](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sleep) does nothing for the specified amount of seconds:

```
sleep(rand(4*60)) # does nothing for anywhere upto 4 minutes
puts "beep"
```